# Upgrade EMR 5.19 to 5.20

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

As part of EMR Cluster version upgrade to 5.20.0 . All the frameworks in the cluster Big Data Frameworks and AWS Services versions got upgraded to latest versions.

For example :

Spark 2.3.2 to Spark 2.4.0

Presto 0.212 to 0.214

While testing the stability and version compatibility with the application we got 1 major issue.

i.e., aws cli is not working because of aws config file in the cluster is getting created with region name as null.

Error in the config file:

s3 = signature_version = s3v4

region = null

Given i am a Developer or Tester when i create a new EMR Cluster with Jenkins pipeline the error above should be resolved and aws cli should work without any failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same problems, on this thread on the aws forum they say that this error could be fixed running:

> aws configure set default.region eu-west-1

in the bootstrap script.

See: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=883372#883372

Comment: Thank You for responding. This helped